# How to get around the asynchronous Node.js behaviour?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm working on a script that pings websites and returns the results in a web UI. However, I've run into a problem which I am trying to figure out the best solution for.

This block of code needs to return a array of statuses but due to the asynchronous behaviour of Node.js, it returns an empty array because the code takes time to execute.

Here is what I have:

```
var ping = require('ping');

function checkConnection(hosts) {

    var results = [];

    hosts.forEach(function (host) {
        ping.sys.probe(host, function (isAlive) {
            results.push({"host": host, "status": isAlive});
        });
    });

    return {results: results, timestamp: new Date().getTime()};
}

module.exports.checkConnection = checkConnection;
```

I know that you could solve this problem with the use of timers but what would be the simples and most ideal solution here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to get around the asynchronous Node.js behaviour?

Don't. Instead, *embrace* it, by having your `checkConection` accept a callback or return a promise.

Callback example:

```
function checkConnection(hosts, callback) {

    var results = [];

    hosts = hosts.slice(0); // Copy
    hosts.forEach(function (host) {
        ping.sys.probe(host, function (isAlive) {
            results.push({"host": host, "status": isAlive});
            if (results.length === hosts.length) {
                callback({results: results, timestamp: new Date().getTime()});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Note the defensive shallow copy of `hosts`. If you don't do that, then since this code runs asynchronously, the calling code could add to or remove from the `hosts` array while you were processing responses, and the lengths would never match.

An alternate way to handle that without copying is to simply count how many requests you've initiated:

```
function checkConnection(hosts, callback) {

    var results = [];
    var requests = hosts.length;

    hosts.forEach(function (host) {
        ping.sys.probe(host, function (isAlive) {
            results.push({"host": host, "status": isAlive});
            if (results.length === requests) {
                callback({results: results, timestamp: new Date().getTime()});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

That *looks like* it sets up a race condition (what if something modifies `hosts` after you set `requests` but before you're done initiating your `probe` queries?) but it doesn't, because Node runs your JavaScript on a single thread, so no other code can reach in and modify `hosts` between the `requests = hosts.length` and `hosts.forEach` lines.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Like T.J. said, you will need to embrace asynchronous behavior if you are going to program in node.js as that is a fundamental tenet of how it works and how you code a responsive, scalable server using node.js.

T.J.'s answer is a straightforward way of solving this particular problem.  But, since async issues will arise over and over again in node.js, promises can be a very useful tool for managing asynchronous behavior and they quickly become indispensable for more complicated multi-operation sequences with robust error handling.

So, here's a solution to your coding issue using Promises:

```
var ping = require('ping');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

// make a version of ping.sys.probe that returns a promise when done
ping.sys.probeAsync = function(host) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ping.sys.probe(host, function(isAlive) {
            resolve({"host": host, "status": isAlive});
        });
    }
}

function checkConnection(hosts) {
    var promises = hosts.map(function(host) {
        return ping.sys.probeAsync(host);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
        return {results: results, timestamp: new Date().getTime()};
    });
}

module.exports.checkConnection = checkConnection;
```

Sample Usage:

```
myModule.checkConnection(myArrayOfHosts).then(function(results) {
    // results is the {results: results, timestamp: time} object
});
```

Step-by-step, here's how this works:

1. Load the Bluebird promise library.
2. Create a promisified version of `ping.sys.probe` called `ping.sys.probeAsync` that returns a promise that will be resolved when the underlying call is done.
3. Using `.map()` on your array, create an array of promises from calling `ping.sys.probeAsync` on each item in the array.
4. Using `Promise.all()`, create a new promise that is the aggregation of all the promises in the array.  It will call it's `.then()` handler only when all the promises in the array have been resolved (e.g. have finished).
5. Add a `.then()` handler to `Promise.all()` so the timestamp can be added to the results.
6. Return the `Promise.all()` promise so the caller of `checkConnection()` gets a promise back they can use.
7. When calling `checkConnection()` use a `.then()` handler to know when all the operations are done and to obtain the results.

---

Hopefully you can see that once you have a promisified version of your function and you understand how promises work, you can then write the actual async code much simpler.  And, if you also had error handling or had a sequence of async operations that had to be run one after the other (something you don't have here), the advantages of using promises is even greater.

---

P.S. I think Bluebird's `Promise.map()` can be used to combine the `hosts.map()` and `Promise.all()` into a single call, but I've not used that function myself so I didn't offer it here.

Comment: `plus 1` *(blasted asinine [+1 filter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments))* I mentioned promises but haven't used any specific Promise lib in Node so didn't give an example.